# SFDX to MDAPI using multiple paths

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I've been developing my application using a Salesforce DX trial org (and accompanying CLI).  My sfdc-project.json file is setup to use two paths for the source code as follows:

```
{ ...
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "path": "http-sdk"
    }
  ],
...
}
```

This has worked well for me to split my code base up between my app code and a set of HTTP API SDK classes I use.  However, now that I'm trying to convert the project to an MDAPI format for packaging and distribution in the AppExchange, I noticed that the `sfdx force:source:convert -d mdapioutput/` command only outputs the contents of the *default* path from my config.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

If you run the command multiple times with the same output directly:

```
sfdx force:source:convert -r force-app -d mdapioutput/
sfdx force:source:convert -r http-sdk -d mdapioutput/
```

it does seem to merge the files correctly, but it does not properly merge the `package.xml` (will be overwritten with the last commands xml).

However, while undocumented, that you can put multiple packages under force-app and do something like this:

**File Structure**

```
- force-app
-- main
---- classes
---- pages
-- http-sdk
---- classes
---- pages
```

**sfdx-project.json**

```
{ ...
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "path": "force-app/main"
    },
    {
      "path": "force-app/http-sdk"
    }
  ],
...
}
```

You can then run: `sfdx force:source:convert -r force-app -d mdapioutput/` to package both.

With this setup you can still package both individually:

`sfdx force:source:convert -r force-app/http-sdk -d mdapioutput/`

***Disclaimer*** : I haven't tested this setup with scratch orgs so I'm not sure if `force:source:pull` and `force:source:pull` will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to indicate the root as well for the source convert

Have you tried below

```
sfdx force:source:convert -r http-sdk -d mdapioutput/
```

Comment: Unfortunately it just uses that folder to copy the contents into the mdapioutput  directory.  I tried using `-r http-sdk,force-app` and that fails completely as it looks like it uses the -r argument to build just a single path.

Comment: I guess you will need to run convert command first with force-app and then with http-sdk for this .

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but I came into this issue and to fix it I've used the following, it has packaged my 3 packages together in the mdapioutput dir

```
sfdx force:source:convert -d mdapioutput/ -r .
```